# using multiple if statements in function

Tags: python, excel, element

Here is my code:

```
ac = a + c
bd = b + d

indices = random.sample(range(len(ac)),len(ac))
ac = list(map(ac.__getitem__, indices))
bd = list(map(bd.__getitem__, indices))


with open('DD{}.csv'.format(fileName), 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow(['trial','target location',' source target',' source distractor','target','rt'])

    for i in range(len(ac)):

        loc = [1, 2]
        location = random.choice(loc)
        if location == 1:
            pos1 = [.05,.05]
            pos2 = [-.05, -.05]
        else:
            pos1 = [-.05, -.05]
            pos2 = [.05, .05]

        distractorstim = visual.ImageStim(win=win, pos=pos1, size=[0.5,0.5])
        distractorstim.autoDraw = True
        targetstim = visual.ImageStim(win=win, pos=pos2, size=[0.5,0.5])
        targetstim.autoDraw = True

        targetstim.image = ac[i]
        distractorstim.image = bd[i]
        win.flip()
        trialClock.reset()
        core.wait(.05)
        rt = trialClock.getTime()
        for el in ac:
            if el in a:
                target = 'congruent'
            else:
                target = 'incongruent'



    writer.writerow([i,location,ac[i],bd[i],target,rt])
```

So what this code does it it logs a bunch of information about a stimulus into an excel file. However, when I try to use the element function ('if el') to log data that is from list 'a', it will only log the last value repetitively. If I move the element function  I can get it to log for each trial, but it will only log the last value for all everything else. Any idea how I might fix this? Any advice will be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: 97.2% of all Python problems can be fixed if you just examine your indentation. Sometimes I think the indentation method of flow control was one of the worst decisions Guido ever made :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo Have you seen C/C++/Java/JavaScript code written by someone who doesn't give a damn about indentation? In Python it's impossible.

Comment: @Brett, could you give an example (input and output) of: how code works and how it should work?

Comment: @pawelswiecki, yes, it _is_ impossible. What _is_ possible however is that it's easy to write invalid code that _looks_ perfectly okay (because most editors/terminals don't tell you what's a tab and what's a space), something that doesn't happen in C, for example, if you use braces. You're right in one important way, it's possible to write badly formatted code in those non-Python languages.

Answer (score 2):

In the last for loop, you set `target` in each loop iteration, so only the last iteration will  determine the value of target.

maybe something like:

```
target = None
for el in ac:
    if el in a:
        target = 'congruent'
if target is None:
        target = 'incongruent'
```

Comment: He shouldn't break loop, he should either write all of it in that loop, or use a list as you suggest and then later iterate through and write it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Changing:

```
 for el in ac:
        if el in a:
            target = 'congruent'
        else:
            target = 'incongruent'
```

to:

```
    if ac[i] in a:
        target = 'congruent'
    else:
        target = 'incongruent'
```

Seemed to do the trick, thank you to everyone who commented. :)